# Get Vim on OSX to open a browser showing URL of current file on repository host

Tags: macos, vim

I'd like to bind a key to open a browser on the current file in our online repo hosting (e.g. actually codebasehq, but imagine it's like github.)

Say I'm editing a file in Vim, named:

```
/ROOT/repository/subdir/filename
```

My current directory is in 'repository', so my statusline displays the filename as:

```
subdir/filename
```

I'm on OSX, so the system command line I'd use to open this in a browser is:

```
open https://<REPOHOST>/projects/<USER>/repositories/<REPOSITORY>/blob/master/<SUBDIR>/<FILENAME>#L<LINE>
```

Where:

- REPOHOST and USER are fixed, I'm happy to hardcode them.
- REPOSITORY is the basename of the parent of my current working dir, i.e. directory 'repository', without the 'ROOT' prefix.
- SUBDIR and FILENAME are the 'subdir/filename' that I'm editing.
- LINE is the current line number

I've gotten as far as this:

```
noremap <leader>o :silent !open URL<cr>
```

and when I replace URL using hardcoded values for *all* of HOSTNAME, etc, then it opens the browser on a hardcoded filename, with the specified line number highlighted. My problem is how to vimscript up the dynamic substitution of my *actual* repository and file names, etc. into the URL in this line.

I'm very familiar with Python, so solutions which involve invoking Vim's built-in Python API would be entirely acceptable.

**edit**

I'm almost there, but still need a vim command that will append the basename of my current dir onto vimscript variable 'url'. With this in place, the answer from romain1 (together with the refinements in my own answer) would do it perfectly.

**end-edit**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

romainl's answer got me going in the right direction, but I've needed a few fixes to it:

- The string concat operator is ".=", not "+="
- I want command "!open" (system command) not "open" (opens a file in vim)
- I don't need quite so many invocations of "expand". I've managed to collapse several of them down to a single "expand('%')".
- I need to escape the '#' char used before "line number", as "\\#" (two backslashes)
- To get my repo name, I assume it's the same name as my PWD, which I assume is the root of my project. Hence I want the basename of the PWD. To get this without invoking too many other executables (which is slower) I use `system('echo -n ${PWD##*/}')`
- To get the current branch name: From Bash, one could use `git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD` (but you need an up-to-date git, `--short` is recent.) I need to strip the trailing newline from this output, so I use `echo -n $(git ... HEAD)`. To invoke that from vim I use system('echo -n $( ... HEAD)')`

This results in the following:

```
function! OpenBrowser()
    let url  = "https://rangespan.codebasehq.com/projects/rangespan/repositories/"
    " assume repo name == basename(pwd)
    " use 'echo -n' to strip trailing \n char from output
    let url .= system('echo -n ${PWD##*/}')

    let url .= "/blob/"

    " branchname
    " use 'echo -n' to strip trailing \n char from output
    let url .= system('echo -n $(git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD)')

    let url .= "/"

    " filename relative to pwd, which is assumed to be root of repo
    let url .= expand('%')

    " line number
    let url .= "\\#L"
    let url .= line('.')

    execute "!open " . url

endfunction

nnoremap <leader>o :call OpenBrowser()<CR>
```

Now while editing a file in Vim, hitting `,` then `o` opens a browser window on my current file in the upstream repo, with the current line highlighted. This is useful for sending my colleagues links in emails or chat, so they can look at the same source I'm currently looking at. Yay, etc.

Comment: :-) OK, I'll have a try. I have autochdir off anyway, so that my currenct dir is always the root of whatever project I'm working on. I was hoping though, that I could make one that would work no matter what my directory structure looks like. All have to do is figure out vimscript for "basename $PWD". Anyhow, Thanks for the advice! More as it happens.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work:

```
let g:repohost = "whatever"
let g:user     = "whatever"
nnoremap <leader>o :execute "open https://".g:repohost."/projects/".g:user."/repositories/".expand('%:h:h:t')."/blob/master/".expand('%:h:t')."/".expand('%:p:t')."#L".line('.')
```

***edit***

Wrapping the URL building in a function could be a good idea for clarity and maintainability:

```
let g:repohost = "whatever"
let g:user     = "whatever"
function! OpenBrowser()
    let url  = "https://"
    let url .= g:repohost
    let url .= "/projects/"
    let url .= g:user
    let url .= "/repositories/"
    let url .= expand('%:h:h:t')
    let url .= "/blob/master/"
    let url .= expand('%:h:t')
    let url .= "/"
    let url .= expand('%:p:t')
    let url .= "#L"
    let url .= line('.')
    execute "open " . url
endfunction
nnoremap <leader>o :call OpenBrowser()<CR>
```

From there, you can add all kinds of safety checks and even platform specific goodness.

***endedit***

See `:h filename-modifiers`.

Did you try [Fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive)'s `:Gbrowse` command?

Comment: Looks good. Let me try it out tonight or tomorrow and you've got an chosen answer. FWIW I'm also looking up the expand function and modifiers you used so that I'm a bit closer to figuring it by myself next time. Thanks!

Comment: I've had to make a few fixes to your answer, but you definitely set me out in the right direction. I'll outline them in a different answer for clarity, but I'll choose your answer when it's finally 100% working...

Comment: @JonathanHartley, could you ping me when your answer is up?

Comment: Hey. I want to give you as many points as I can because without your answer I would have never gotten there, but I can't pick your answer as the right one because obviously that's misleading to other readers. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: I don't care for the points. What's important is that you have your solution and that others can find it too if they have the same needs.